# Is "tobogán" an acceptable word for "slide" throughout the Spanish speaking world?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, vocabulario

## English

I'm trying to learn words to talk to my baby at the playground in Spanish.  WordReference.com gives the following as part of its definition for "slide."

> slide 2 sustantivo 1. (in playground, pool) tobogán m, resbaladilla f (Méx), rodadero m (Col), resbalín m (Chi)

Since the word "tobogán" does not have a regional qualifier, I would assume it is an acceptable word in any region.  Is this true?

---

## Español

Trato de aprender palabras para hablar con mi bebé en el parque en español.  WordReference.com da lo siguiente como parte de su definición para "slide."

> slide 2 sustantivo 1. (in playground, pool) tobogán m, resbaladilla f (Méx), rodadero m (Col), resbalín m (Chi)

Ya que la palabra "tobogán" no tiene un calificador regional, supongo que es una palabra aceptable en cualquiera región. ¿Es verdad?

Comment: Is this question about worldwide usage, or Spanish usage.

Comment: The questions is about usage in Spanish speaking countries worldwide. Question edited for clarity.

Comment: In English the word "tobogán" is a synonym of "sled" (trineo para usar en la nieve)

Answer (score 9):

## English

I'm pretty sure in Spain we only use **tobogán**. I have never heard the other words. I'm not sure if **tobogán** is used in every Spanish speaking areas (so I'm not really fully answering your question)

---

## Español

En España estoy bastante seguro de que solamente utilizamos **tobogán**. Nunca he escuchado las otras palabras. No estoy seguro de si **tobogán** se utiliza en todo el mundo hispanohablante, así que no estoy contestando tu pregunta del todo.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it is, at least, acceptable and common to use in Spain.

Comment: I've never heard anything apart from *tobogán* in Spain either. Well, except the Basque *txirrista* in the Basque Country.

Answer (score 5):

In Mexico, `tobogán` is a valid word, however (at least as Northern Mexico is concerned) `tobogán` usually refers to a considerably big enough slide (Regardless of water, there's a few of those big slides in a couple parks in the city where I live) like this:

[image]

As a part of daily conversation, I'd use `resbaladilla` or `resbaladero` over `tobogán` when refering to a playground slide, but I wouldn't consider it wrong or anything.

Answer (score 4):

In the southern parts of Mexico (I'm form Puebla) `tobogán` is only used for water slides while `resbaladilla` is used for a non-water slide (regardless of size)

Answer (score 4):

In Argentina `tobogán` is the common word, almost exclusively (never heard of `resbaladilla` or the alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

`Tobogán` is indeed the universal Word for the slides, so you can go to any Spanish speaking country and say it, will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Colombia use *tobogán* for a big slide specially if it is like a tube and has curves (wet or dry). And *rodadero* referring to a children's playground slide.

Answer (score 0):

"Tobogán" is officially in the Spanish dictionary with that meaning. However, I am not sure if it is commonly used in Spanish-speaking languages.  For example, in Puerto Rico (where I am from) we used the word "chorrera" which doesn't mean "slide" at all. But that is the word commonly accepted in that region.  I know in Spain, Mexico, and a few other Latin American countries they used this word correctly.  I also know that the overwhelming majority of Spanish-speaking people will understand if you use the word "***resbaladilla***" or "***resbaladero***"; even in Puerto Rico.

Answer (score 0):

In Chile, a **tobogán** is big, probably you have to pay to use it, while a **resbalín** (also *resfalín*, *refalín*, *rascapoto* and *raspapoto*) is small, probably find it in a public place or in the backyard of a kindergarten.

Answer (score 0):

As complement to [@AmparadoLento's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10304/5764), *tobogán* is a word generally known for reference wet slides (also known as *tobogán acuático / o de agua*).

[Image results for tobogán](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=rodadero&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1LHyt4qYyQIVAzwmCh1IAQ0D#tbm=isch&q=tobogan) in Google.

While *rodadero* is more related to small slides (dry) used by kids.

[Image results of rodadero infantil](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=rodadero&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1LHyt4qYyQIVAzwmCh1IAQ0D#tbm=isch&q=rodadero%20infantil) in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of having water or not, size, shape, color and the material the Castilian Spanish word known and used and understood and accepted by all the 22 countries having Spanish as the official language is the word “ tobogán”. This word is the word found in the Real Academia Española of correct Spanish.Any other word is not going to be understood by all these countries.